# Excel VBA Submit all records with Criteria

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have am trying to complete a function that will submit all records to my excel spreadsheet from a separate spreadsheet, if it matches two criteria's:

- Previously Added Not = "Yes"
- Proposed Action = "Pass"

Currently I have written the code so that it will populate the next record from a request spreadsheet that has not previously been added to the tracker (This workbook), however, every time I try to get it to loop based on the criteria it doesn't work.

```
Private Sub CmdB_SubmitAll_Click()

Dim wRequest As Workbook
Dim xComponentDetails as Worksheet
Dim ReqLRow As Long
Dim ReqRow As Long
Dim Count As Long
Dim CountDown As Integer
Dim CountUp As Integer

Set wRequest = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
Set xComponentDetails = wRequest.Worksheets("Component Data")

ReqLRow = xComponentDetails.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Me.CB_Client.Value = ""

With xComponentDetails

        For Count = (ReqRow + 1) To ReqLRow + 1 Step 1
            If Not .Range("W" & Count).Value = "Yes" and Me.TB_PropAction = "Pass" Then
                Call GetBulkRequestData
                            
                ReqRow = Count
                CountUp = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(xComponentDetails.Range("W2:W" & Count), "")
                CountDown = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(xComponentDetails.Range("W" & Count & ":W" & ReqLRow + 1), "")
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Count
        
    If CountUp = 1 Then
        Me.CmdB_Previous.Enabled = False
        Else: Me.CmdB_Previous.Enabled = True
    End If
    
    If CountDown = 1 Then
        MsgBox "No Further Component Requests"
        Me.CmdB_Next.Enabled = False
        Else: Me.CmdB_Next.Enabled = True
    End If
End With

wRequest.Save

End Sub
```

I'm not a professional coder therefore, any assistance would be gratefully received.

Comment: This `For Count = (ReqRow + 1) To ReqLRow + 1 Step 1` is exactly the same as `For Count = (0 + 1) To ReqLRow + 1 Step 1` because `ReqRow` is not initialized and is `0` when the loop runs first. No matter how often you change `ReqRow = Count` inside the loop it will not affect the `For` loop once it has started! • If you want to mess around with the loop counter never use a `For` loop, then switch over to a `Do` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, although I’m not sure if I fully understand what you have said. Is it as simple as changing from For Loop just change this to Do Loop?

Comment: Well, since I didn't understand what exactly you are trying to do I cannot answer that entirely. Actually your `For` loop doesn't make much sense to me neither. I can't see what your intention was here. Maybe you can give a [mcve] of your problem and some example input and desired output data. Screenshots might help too to explain where exactly you got stuck. Also try to explain what *"it doesn't work."* means because that's a pretty useless error description, can you be more precise here?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will try and explain what happens, the code I have provided tries to combine a piece of code that works and will select the next line from a Microsoft Forms Spreadsheet that hasn't already been reviewed by our management team.

What I'm trying to do is automate the process slightly. So what happens is that when you click submit it will bring in the line unreviewed line (hence if Not "Yes"), and it brings the line data into a form.

There is a function that Analyses the data and returns a Value, Where if "Pass", it will write to my sheet and Loop to the next.

Comment: Sorry would try and add a screenshot, but with the level of my account it won't allow me to. I can share a link to my OneDrive if that helps?